# Controller method does not work

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, controllers, admin-controller

I'm using Magento 1.8.1.0 community edition.

I have managed to add a custom admin controller and the default indexAction() method does work. However, if I try to access the other method, anotherAction() I get redirected to the Admin dashboard.

Swapping the methods' names works, so I don't think there is any issue with the code in the other method and caching has been turned off.

The 2 URLs in question are:

- http://dev.printo.in/index.php/category_info/index/index
- http://dev.printo.in/index.php/category_info/index/another

I did a little digging and discovered that the request to the /another action is met with a 302 redirection to the admin dashboard.

Any pointers on what the issue could be?

Basically I'm trying to add a new controller with 2 actions as a new admin page. I do not want to change / override the current functionality.

Thanks in advance!

```
<?

class Printo_CategoryAttribute_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    private $filepath = 'var/import/latest_categories.csv'; // location of file

    public function indexAction()
    {   
        $category = Mage::getModel ('catalog/category');
        $tree = $category->getTreeModel ();
        $tree->load ();
        $ids = $tree->getCollection()->getAllIds();

        if ($ids)
    {
       mkdir('var/import');
       file_put_contents($this->filepath,"Category ID, Category Name" . PHP_EOL);

           foreach ( $ids as $id )
           {
               $string = $id . ', ' .$category->load($id)->getName() . PHP_EOL;
               file_put_contents($this->filepath,$string,FILE_APPEND);
            }

           $x = print_r(get_class_methods($this),TRUE);
       $this->loadLayout();
           //create a text block with the name of "printo-block"
           $block = $this->getLayout()
           ->createBlock('core/text', 'printo-block')
           ->setText("<h1><a href ='/category_info/index/download'>Download</a></h1><h2><pre>$x</pre></h2>");

           $this->_setActiveMenu('printo_menu/category_info');  

           $this->_addContent($block);
           $this->renderLayout();
        }
    }


    public function downloadAction()
    {
/*            
           $this->getResponse()
                    ->setHttpResponseCode(200)
                    ->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/csv', TRUE)
                    ->setHeader('Content-Length', filesize($this->filepath), TRUE)
                    ->setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="latest_categories.csv"', TRUE);
           $this->getResponse()->clearBody();
           $this->getResponse()->sendHeaders();
           readfile($this->filepath);

           $this->loadLayout();
           //create a text block with the name of "printo-block"
           $block = $this->getLayout()
           ->createBlock('core/text', 'printo-block')
           ->setText("<h1>YAY IT WORKS!</h1>");
           $this->_setActiveMenu('printo_menu/category_info');
           $this->_addContent($block);
           $this->renderLayout();
*/
       $fileName ='Category Info.csv';
       $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($filename, file_get_contents($this->filepath));
     }

}


?>
```

Here is the config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Printo_CategoryAttribute>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Printo_CategoryAttribute>
    </modules>

    <admin>
        <routers>
            <Printo_CategoryAttribute_Admin_Page>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Printo_CategoryAttribute</module>
                    <frontName>category_info</frontName>
                </args>
            </Printo_CategoryAttribute_Admin_Page>
        </routers>
    </admin>

   <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <printo_menu translate="title" module="CategoryAttribute">
                <title>Printo</title> 
                <sort_order>5000</sort_order>
                <children>
                    <category_info module="CategoryAttribute">
                        <title>Category Info</title> 
                        <action>category_info/index/index</action>
                    </category_info>
                </children>
            </printo_menu>
        </menu> 
    </adminhtml>

    <global>

    <helpers>
        <CategoryAttribute>
            <class>Printo_CategoryAttribute_Helper</class>
        </CategoryAttribute>
    </helpers>

    <resources>
            <add_category_attribute>
                <setup>
        <module>Printo_CategoryAttribute</module>
        <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </add_category_attribute>
            <add_category_attribute_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </add_category_attribute_write>
            <add_category_attribute_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </add_category_attribute_read>
    </resources>
    </global>

</config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what the issue was. You need to use:

```
$url = $this->getUrl('category_info/index/download');
```

to get the full url including the key used to authenticate the current logged-in session.

The result of this is that, you get a link like so

```
http://dev.printo.in/index.php/category_info/index/download/key/4745379c10d9a5fa01bb4bb4645b59bc/
```

Earlier I was just using category_info/index/download and that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you add this custom admin controller

### Using Rewrite Admincontroller:

then it should be

```
SiteUrl/admin/index/index
```

Whenever  rewrite like

```
<admin>
<routers>
    <adminhtml>
    <args>
        <modules>
        <Printo_CategoryAttribute before="Mage_Adminhtml">Printo_CategoryAttribute</Printo_CategoryAttribute>
        </modules>
    </args>
    </adminhtml>
</routers>
</admin>
```

According to `SiteanmeUrl/admin/controllername/ActionName`

.See [at](http://www.justonestepsolutions.net/2012/12/how-to-override-admin-controller-action-in-magento.html)

### Using basic admin url define:

If http://dev.printo.in/index.php/category_info/index/index work whenever admin route config

**like**

```
<admin>
<routers>
    <customadmin>
    <use>admin</use>
    <args>
        <module>Printo_CategoryAttribute</module>
        <frontName>category_info</frontName>
    </args>
    </category_info>
</routers>
</admin>
```